# Adding requested data to a collection using backbone.marionette

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

In my backbone model i'm trying to fire off a request to the server to populate a collection from some JSON:

```
{
"accountType":["Full","Trial"]
}
```

in my account.js model i have:

```
accountManager.module("Entities", function(Entities, accountManager,Backbone, Marionette, $, _){

Entities.account = Backbone.Model.extend({});

Entities.accountCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Entities.account,
comparator: "account",
url:"webapp/jsonData"
});


var API = {
getaccountEntities: function(){
var accounts = new Entities.accountCollection();
accounts.fetch();
if(accounts.length === 0){
console.log("No profiles loaded");
}
return accounts;
}};

accountManager.reqres.setHandler("account:entities", function(){
    return API.getaccountEntities();
});
});
```

Controller.js

```
accountManager.module("accountsApp.List", function(List, accountManager,Backbone, Marionette, $, _){

List.Controller = {
    listaccounts: function(){
        var accounts = accountManager.request("account:entities");
        var accountsListView = new List.accounts({
        collection: accounts});
        accountManager.mainRegion.show(accountsListView);
        }
    };
});
```

app.js

```
var profileManager = new Marionette.Application();

profileManager.addRegions({
 mainRegion: "#main-region",
});

 profileManager.on("initialize:after", function(){
 profileManager.profilesApp.List.Controller.listprofiles();
 });
```

How do i populate a collection with the returned data, and then display it in a view?

Following along with the tutorial in a book i own but just cannot seem to make it work.

The console logs error (so i know it's not getting the data) and i'm also getting an error:

'Uncaught ReferenceError: account is not defined'

Any advice?

Comment: What does your API return? Is it returning a collection? From your question above, it looks like you're trying to fetch a model into a collection.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I've updated my question, i'm following through the persisted data section, it works when i was returning static data but soon as i'm trying to populate the collection from the server i'm running into problems.

Comment: I've added the code from my app.js, account.js and controller.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to initialize a collection by using an API enpoint that doesn't return a collection. "webapp/jsonData" needs tor eturn something like

```
[
  { id: 1, name: "account 1", type: "Full"},
  { id: 2, name: "account 2", type: "Trial"},
  { id: 3, name: "account 3", type: "Full"}
]
```

Notice that it's an array of objects, where each object will become a model in the collection.

In particular, the followign JSON (per your question) can't create a collection:

```
{
  "accountType":["Full","Trial"]
}
```

Instead, if you want a collection of account types, your JSON needs to be something like

```
[
  {name: "Full"},
  {name: "Trial"}
]
```

There's also a slight error in your collection: the `comparator` value needs to be an object attribute. In other words, it will only work if each account model has a "account" attribute.

Comment: Oh okay i understand, i have a games collection which i'll use following this process, i'll have to work something else out to get the account types and populate a drop down, thanks